# Is it possible to dynamically change the URI that an asp.net core process is listening on?

Tags: web-services, asp.net-core

I'd like to have the following architecture:

- A factory web service that is running all the time under a general URI, say /service.
- A set of specific self-hosted application services, running under specific URI, say /service/appA/db1, /service/appA/db2, /service/appB/.  The application services are facades on top of legacy applications, and each application-database pair must be in a separate process.  I cannot merge them.  There may be thousands of combinations of these separate services, so I don't want to kick them all off.  I'd like to kick them off on demand.

Now I could have the client ask the factory to kick off the needed service, and then connect to it, but this doesn't work cleanly in a load-balanced environment.

What I would really like to do is for the factory service to listen to requests, and automatically kick off the application services as needed and then stop listening to the portion of the URI that the newly kicked off service is listening to.

For example, say that client wants to call "http://hostname/service/productapp/myproductdb/products/get/byname"

The first call would go to the factory service.  It would kick off the application service "productapp-myproductdb" and redirect the initial call to the name URL, and stop listening on the URI "/service/productapp/myproductdb".

Any subsequent calls would go directly to the "productapp-myproductdb" service, which would be listening on the "/service/productapp/myproductdb" uri.

I don't want to redirect calls from the factory service to the application service.  I want the client to be able to connect to the application service directly after the initial request.

1. Is this something that is possible to do?
2. If it is possible, how can I do it in ASP.NET Core?

thanks,
Alex

Comment: Proxy Middleware may help you https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Proxy/ProxyMiddleware.cs

Comment: @Set: Proxy middleware would redirect every request through the factory service to the application service, thus pushing requests through two services.  Ideally, I would like this to happen at Http.sys-level and thus avoid hitting the factory service completely.